# Why cannot change checkbox color whatever I do?

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox, colors

I try to style checkbox background color, but it won't change whatever I do. I am using firefox 29 latest.

Is there some rule changes in css or may be in the browser?

**CSS:**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    background: #990000;    
}

.chk {
   background-color: #990000;
}
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/6KXRg/

Comment: @blueygh2 more like a perfect duplicate, lol.

Comment: thanks guys...! I already read that, just want to make sure what is the problem!

Comment: CSS add new property  `accent-color: red;` to change checkbox and radio button 
default colour.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Checkboxes are not able to be styled.  You would need a third party js plugin there are many available.

If you want to do this yourself it basically involves hiding the checkbox creating an element and styling that as you want then binding its click event to two functions one to change its look and another to activate the click event of the checkbox.

The same problem will arise when trying to style that little down arrow on a drop-down select element.

Comment: This is not exactly true. In fact, you can style checkboxes quite easily with a few lines of CSS. No need for third-party plugins...the real problem is cross-browser compatibility, but that's for everything. I will post my answer simply for the sake of completeness for people looking for this. Cheers -

Answer (score 193):

You can now simply use the [accent-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color) property :

```css
#cb1 {
  accent-color: #9b59b6;
}

#cb2 {
  accent-color: #34495e;
}

#cb3 {
  accent-color: #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" checked />
<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" checked />
<input id="cb3" type="checkbox" checked />
```

*Note : as this is a new feature, it is not supported by all browsers, but it is still useful*

[Here is a compatibility link](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_accent-color)

Comment: It seems Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox are now [supporting this](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_accent-color).

Comment: here is the Browser compatibility [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 95):

Technically, it is possible to change the color of anything with CSS. As mentioned, you can't change the background-color or color but you can use CSS filters. For example:

```
input[type="checkbox"] { /* change "blue" browser chrome to yellow */
  filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(18deg) brightness(1.7);
}
```

If you are really looking for design control over checkboxes though, your best bet is to do the "hidden" checkbox and style an adjacent element such as a div.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one meanwhile (hue-rotate should be enough to adapt the color)

Comment: This answer is better than other answers! Thank you.

Comment: Okay, But the color of checkboxes differs on different browsers and devices.

Comment: Very clever :)
However, It's weird that we have to do this in 2021 )

Comment: Golden solution !

Answer (score 70):

Although the question is answered and is older, In exploring some options to overcome the the styling of check boxes issue I encountered this awesome set of CSS3 only styling of check boxes and radio buttons controlling background colors and other appearances. Thought this might be right up the alley of this question.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghw5kaco/)

```css
body {
    background: #555;
}

h1 {
    color: #eee;
    font: 30px Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* SLIDE ONE */
.slideOne {
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.slideOne label {
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -3px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.slideOne input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    left: 37px;
}

/* SLIDE TWO */
.slideTwo {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.slideTwo:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 14px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 52px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #111;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.slideTwo label {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.slideTwo label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #333;
    left: 6px;
    top: 6px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.slideTwo input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    left: 54px;
}

.slideTwo input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    background: #00bf00;
}

/* SLIDE THREE */
.slideThree {
    width: 80px;
    height: 26px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.slideThree:after {
    content: 'OFF';
    font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
}

.slideThree:before {
    content: 'ON';
    font: 12px/26px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #00bf00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.slideThree label {
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 20px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.slideThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    left: 43px;
}

/* ROUNDED ONE */
.roundedOne {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
}

.roundedOne label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.roundedOne label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #00bf00;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.roundedOne label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.roundedOne input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

/* ROUNDED TWO */
.roundedTwo {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
}

.roundedTwo label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.roundedTwo label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 5px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.roundedTwo label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.roundedTwo input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

/* SQUARED ONE */
.squaredOne {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
    margin: 20px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
}

.squaredOne label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.squaredOne label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #00bf00;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #00bf00 0%, #009400 100%);

    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.squaredOne label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredOne input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

/* SQUARED TWO */
.squaredTwo {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
    margin: 20px auto;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: relative;
}

.squaredTwo label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.squaredTwo label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredTwo label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredTwo input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}


/* SQUARED THREE */
.squaredThree {
    width: 20px;    
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.squaredThree label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.squaredThree label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

/* SQUARED FOUR */
.squaredFour {
    width: 20px;    
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.squaredFour label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.squaredFour label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredFour label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.squaredFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS3 Checkbox Styles</h1>

<!-- Slide ONE -->
<div class="slideOne">  
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideOne" name="check" />
    <label for="slideOne"></label>
</div>

<!-- Slide TWO -->
<div class="slideTwo">  
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideTwo" name="check" />
    <label for="slideTwo"></label>
</div>

<!-- Slide THREE -->
<div class="slideThree">    
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="slideThree" name="check" />
    <label for="slideThree"></label>
</div>

<!-- Rounded ONE -->
<div class="roundedOne">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedOne" name="check" />
    <label for="roundedOne"></label>
</div>

<!-- Rounded TWO -->
<div class="roundedTwo">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" />
    <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
</div>

<!-- Squared ONE -->
<div class="squaredOne">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredOne" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredOne"></label>
</div>

<!-- Squared TWO -->
<div class="squaredTwo">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredTwo" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredTwo"></label>
</div>

<!-- Squared THREE -->
<div class="squaredThree">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredThree"></label>
</div>

<!-- Squared FOUR -->
<div class="squaredFour">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredFour" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredFour"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: These are cool, but it was a royal pain trying to get text to the side of the checkbox. I'm almost giving up on this.

Comment: to get text on the same line and after the checkbox add `white-space:nowrap;` to the applicable div style

Answer (score 42):

One line of CSS is enough using `hue-rotate filter`. You can change their sizes with `transform: scale()` as well.

```
.checkbox { filter: hue-rotate(0deg) }
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/berkinakkaya/pen/BaKwLKj)

```css
.c1 { filter: hue-rotate(0deg)   }
.c2 { filter: hue-rotate(30deg)  }
.c3 { filter: hue-rotate(60deg)  }
.c4 { filter: hue-rotate(90deg)  }
.c5 { filter: hue-rotate(120deg) }
.c6 { filter: hue-rotate(150deg) }
.c7 { filter: hue-rotate(180deg) }
.c8 { filter: hue-rotate(210deg) }
.c9 { filter: hue-rotate(240deg) }

input[type=checkbox] {
  transform: scale(2);
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Prevent cursor being `text` between checkboxes */
body { cursor: default }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="c1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c6" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c7" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c8" />
<input type="checkbox" class="c9" />
```

Comment: this is limited to some colors.

Comment: Nice, but does nothing for MS Edge, alas.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work for MS Edge.

Answer (score 35):

I had the same issue, trying to use large inputs and had a very small checkbox. After some searching, this is good enough for my needs:

```
input[type='checkbox']{
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  margin: 5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance:none;
  outline: 2px solid lightblue;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmz0eswv/)

Maybe someone will find it useful.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, as it replaces a checkbox without any third party plug-in or extensive CSS

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thanks @chriswnl.  I removed the jQuery but still indicate checked status via CSS's `:checked` pseudo class: https://jsfiddle.net/m9zj5Ldw/

Comment: The only problem of this answer is that when selected the checkbox tick doesn't show.

Comment: This was a great answer. I paired with checkbox and it worked well `input[type='checkbox']:checked {background-color: #000;}` and `input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {content: '\2713';color: white;position: absolute;line-height: 1rem;font-size:1rem;padding-left: 0.15rem;}`

Answer (score 29):

Late but as a note: after upgrading Chrome to v/81, all check boxes & radio buttons turned blue. So here is a dead simple solution if you ain't okay with blue but with grayscale;

```css
input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio'] { filter: grayscale(1) }
```

See more on MDN: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/grayscale

Comment: And it can be set to black by using `{ filter: grayscale()100% }`

Answer (score 19):

Yes, you can. Based on knowledge from colleagues here and researching on web, here you have **the best solution** for **styling a checkbox** without any third-party plugin:

```css
input[type='checkbox']{
  width: 14px !important;
  height: 14px !important;
  margin: 5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 1px solid gray;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
  background: red;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
  content: '✔';
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox'>
```

Comment: Correct!  I like the CSS here: -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612798/530047
but this answer works perfectly.

Comment: @Jonathan the link you posted is very interesting, I have not found a way for styling the "check" symbol, the reason I just put "✔" as content. I like your idea!

Comment: A small css improvement in ::after css definitions:
    content: 'L';
    color: white;
    transform: rotate(30deg) scaleX(-1);
    display: inline-block;
Works perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

I also had this problem. I use chrome to code because I'm currently a newbie. I was able to change the colour of the checkboxes and radio selectors when they were checked ONLY using CSS. The current degree that is set in the hue-rotate() turns the blue checks red. I  first used the grayscale(1) with the filter: but you don't need it. However, if you just want plain flat gray, go for the grayscale value for filter.

I've ONLY tested this in Chrome but it works with just plain old HTML and CSS, let me know in the comments section if it works in other browsers.

```css
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  filter: hue-rotate(140deg);
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <label for="radio1">Eau de Toilette</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="example1"><br>
  <label for="radio2">Eau de Parfum</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="example1"><br>
  <label for="check1">Orange Zest</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="example2"><br>
  <label for="check2">Lemons</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="example2"><br>
 </body>
```

Comment: This is a real cool solution!  I'm going to use this with `filter: grayscale(1);`.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 14):

Can be very simplified like that :

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    outline:2px solid red;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Works without any plugin :)

Comment: It didn't work as expected: https://i.imgur.com/XIp44j6.png

Answer (score 6):

you cant change the background of checkbox but some how you can do a trick try this :)

```css
.divBox {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 20px 90px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.divBox label {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
    /* 
    use this background transparent to check the value of checkbox 
    background: transparent;
    */
    background: Black;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.divBox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="divBox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput"name="" />
    <label for="checkboxFourInput"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This should solve it, also the checkmark set in content will center perfectly.

for an html element like:
`<input type="checkbox" />`

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked {
  background-color: rgb(60,69,77,0.9);
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
  content: '\2713';
  color:white;
}
input[type='checkbox']{
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  appearance:none;
  border-radius:10%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(60,69,77,0.9);
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a checkbox with the class (bootstrap) .form-check-input.
Then you can use an image for an example as the check mark.

SCSS code:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
```

```
.form-check-input {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance:none;
    outline: 1px solid blue;

    &:checked
    {
        background: white url('blue.svg') no-repeat; 
        background-size: 20px 20px;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Styling the arrow & the checkbox colors.**

I haven't seen any answer deal with the arrow colors, so I thought I might add this for those wanting to also *style the arrow* inside the checkbox. I'm *not* suggesting to do these things, it's just for demo purposes.

```css
.checkbox-label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    clear: both;
}

.checkbox-label input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-label .checkbox-custom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}


.checkbox-label input:checked ~ .checkbox-custom {
    background-color: #FFEA00;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    opacity:1;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.checkbox-label .checkbox-custom::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 12px;
    top: 12px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid #000;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}


.checkbox-label input:checked ~ .checkbox-custom::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1);
  opacity:1;
  left: 8px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 12px;
  border: solid #000000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-container">
        <label class="checkbox-label">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="checkbox-custom"></span>
        </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Transparency maybe: checkbox inside span

```
<span style="display:inline-block; background-color:silver;padding:0px;margin:0px;height:13px; width:13px; overflow:hidden"><input type="checkbox" style="opacity:0.50;padding:0px;margin:0px" /></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Agree with iLoveTux , applying too many things (many colors and backgrounds) nothing worked , but here's what started working,
Apply these properties to its css:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance:none;
```

and then css styling started working on checkbox :)

Comment: It's also great because it preserves the focus ring