# How to Change CSS Styling on a Checkbox on Hover with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

All I am trying to do is have my checkbox change it's background colour when you hover over it. However, this is made more complicated by the fact that the `td input:checkbox` is dynamically created. I have tried every conceivable approach and I can not get it right. Here is the JQuery I have:

```
/* snip */
    $('.table_products').on('click', 'td input:checkbox', function () {

    $("input:checkbox").hover(function(){
        $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "yellow"});
    }, function(){
        $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "white"});
    });
/* snip */
```

Comment: if it's dynamically create use `$(document).on('hover', 'identifier', function(){`

Comment: Your code makes sense to me, but I think the problem is that checkbox styles aren't editable. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24322691/1601698. Styling checkboxes involve a lot of hacking.

Comment: @smerny, `backgroundColor` is the JavaScript property name and it is perfectly valid to use in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it isn't possible to change the color inside the checkbox square but you can trick as @gavgrif said. I just hover when you pass on the checkbox (not on the entire td):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").hover(function(){
  $(this).closest(".wrapper").css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function(){
  $(this).closest(".wrapper").css("background-color", "white");
});
```

Probably your selector was worng too (the correct way to declare is into []).

I just wrapped the checkbox but you can use your current parent:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
  </div>
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/5V5cUysB9E0SYGMddFKl?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was not aware that checkboxes can not edited. However your solution was a workable compromise. Essentially it highlights the correct row when you hover over the check box. Thanks !