# How to change the colour of an input checkbox on select in css?

Tags: css, checkbox, input

I am working on a form in which I want to change the color of an input checkbox in css. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0zq362c/4/embedded/result) for that.  The snippets of HTML code which I have used in order to make a checkbox is:

```
<div class="form-check mb-3">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
   <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   </label>
</div>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I need to add so that I get different **checkbox color on select**.

I tried with the following css code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
input#gridCheck.form-check-input
{
color: red;
}
```

Comment: you want to change the colour of the text next to the checkbox ?

Comment: When we select the checkbox, it appears to be blue. Is there any way we can change that to any other color ?

Comment: I'm using my mobile phone right now I can't see where is that 'blue' color. Would you mind provide a screenshot ?

Comment: You can't style inputs. By the way, your fiddle uses duplicate IDs. Don't.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322599/css-why-cannot-change-checkbox-color-whatever-i-do

Comment: @MrLister I have used bootstrap to make that form so its all coming from the bootstrap documentation.

Comment: @ths So on select of a checkbox, I can see blue color inside and around the checkbox. Is there any way we can change that ?

Comment: No, that's a default behaviour, you can hide the checkbox and create  custom checkbox by adding some additional markup alongside with some `CSS`. As [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-For-Sliding-Toggle-Switches-LC-Switch.jpg) maybe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css - Why Cannot Change Checkbox Color Whatever I Do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322599/css-why-cannot-change-checkbox-color-whatever-i-do)