# How in SASS i can select an input type checkbox, checked and disabled?

Tags: html, sass

How i can select and style an `<input type=checkbox disabled checked>` in SASS?

I tried this but don't put any style:

```
  input {
    &:checked &:disabled{
      background-color:red;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should write `&:checked:disabled`. But a checkbox doesn't respond to `background-color`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code you can try.

```
input {
    &:checked:disabled{
      background-color:red;
    }
}
```

However the styles won't work for checkbox. As checkbox can not be styled natively yet. See for reference [css - Why Cannot Change Checkbox Color Whatever I Do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322599/css-why-cannot-change-checkbox-color-whatever-i-do)

Comment: Perfect this works. I use this for styling a sibling label with `&:checked:disabled + label`.