# Checkbox styling: changing border color is duplicating border

Tags: html, css

I have the following checkboxes:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  outline: 2px solid #c00;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="arrestData" name="category" value="Category: Arrest Data" class="chkinput">
<label for="vehicle1"> Arrest Data</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="useOfForce" name="category" value="Category: Use of Force" class="chkinput">
<label for="useOfForce"> Use of Force</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="humanTrafficking" name="category" value="Category: Human Trafficking" class="chkinput">
<label for="vehicle3"> Human Trafficking</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="treatmentAndDiversion" name="category" value="Category: Treatment and Diversion" class="chkinput">
<label for="vehicle3"> Treatment and Diversion</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="drugAndOverdoseData" name="category" value="Category: Drug and Overdose Data" class="chkinput">
<label for="vehicle3"> Drug and Overdose Data</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="federalCrimeData" name="category" value="Category: Federal Crime Data" class="chkinput">
<label for="vehicle3"> Federal Crime Data</label><br>
```

When I try to style the border with the css, it simply adds a new border to the existing one.  I want to be able to change border appearance and also the checkmark appearance when checked.  I know this is probably a duplicate question but no example has worked thus far.

Comment: no..can my question be addressed here? thx.

Comment: I’m confused as to why some of the ideas in the question linked by @DiamondJoe12 don’t help you. Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754442/8565010 <- that answer, paired with the code in the last comment by Han, works. You can format it as needed.

Comment: You'll have to a specialized css markup per browser ... not every browser allows for modifying controls the same way. Bootstrap gets around this by hiding the actual control https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/checks-radios/#checkbox-toggle-buttons