# Mozilla select option tick icon ugly

Tags: firefox, html-select

I am on Mac and noticed that the tick icon of a select option looks like this in Mozilla Firefox:

[image: mozilla tick icon]

I'm intended to change the icon to look like in Safari and Google Chrome. Like this:

[image: chrome and safari tick icon]

Anyone knows how to style the select or option element with CSS in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

These icons depend on the font that you use.
If you didn't select yours then the default is used.
Not every web browsers has the same configured and that becouse they are different.

Check this answer:
[How to draw a checkmark / tick using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968531/how-to-draw-a-checkmark-tick-using-css)

How to change this should be solved right there^.